# Get event trigger

Tags: wpf, selectionchanged

I am using WPF `ListBox`, binding the `ItemsSource` to an `ObservableCollection`.

I subscribed to the `SelectionChanged` event, which will notify me when the user select/deselect any `ListItem`.

Now, can I get whether the selection in the `ListBox` was changed due to user click or Collection change (i.e. items were removed from the Collection which were selected in the `ListBox`) ??

Comment: Surely *you* know when you remove some items from the collection, so you could set a `bool` flag as you remove something and then ignore calls to the handler when the flag is `true`... of course, don't forget to set the flag to `false` again afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

As *you* know when you remove some items from the collection, you could set a `bool` flag as you remove something and then ignore calls to the handler when the flag is `true`... of course, don't forget to set the flag to `false` again afterwards:

```
isProgramAction = true;
Items.Remove(item);
isProgramAction = false;
```

...

```
private void SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!isProgramAction) 
    {
        // User Action
    }
}
```